# Variable resets to default value between onClickListeners

Tags: java, android

I don't understand why my variable is reset to it's default. I click on the listView, which sets the variable currentAssessment to the ID of the retrieved record. Then I click to delete the record with the chosen ID and it's been reset.

```java
package com.breathetaichi.classtracker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static DBInterface db;
    private static ArrayList<Course> allCourses = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Assessment> allAssessments = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Instructor> allInstructors = new ArrayList<>();
    private int courseCalled;
    private int currentAssessment = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

//        currentAssessment = -1;

        db = new DBInterface(CourseActivity.this);
        db.getWritableDatabase();

        allCourses = db.getCourses();
        allAssessments = db.getAssessments();
        allInstructors = db.getInstructors();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        courseCalled = extras.getInt("courseID");

        String courseTitle = "";
        int courseTermID = -1;
        int courseInstructorID = -1;
        String courseStartDateStr = "";
        String courseEndDateStr = "";
        String courseStatusStr = "";
        String courseNoteStr = "";
        for(Course course : allCourses) {
            if(course.getId() == courseCalled) {
                courseTitle = course.getTitle();
                courseTermID = course.getTermID();
                courseInstructorID = course.getInstructorID();
                courseStartDateStr = course.getStartDate();
                courseEndDateStr = course.getEndDate();
                courseStatusStr = course.getStatus();
                courseNoteStr = course.getNote();
            }
        }

        EditText courseName = findViewById(R.id.course_title);
        courseName.setText(courseTitle);
        EditText courseStartDate = findViewById(R.id.course_start_date);
        courseStartDate.setText(courseStartDateStr);
        EditText courseEndDate = findViewById(R.id.course_end_date);
        courseEndDate.setText(courseEndDateStr);
        EditText courseStatus = findViewById(R.id.course_status);
        courseStatus.setText(courseStatusStr);
        EditText termEndDate = findViewById(R.id.course_note);
        termEndDate.setText(courseNoteStr);

        int instructorID = courseInstructorID;
        String instructorNameStr = "";
        String instructorPhoneStr = "";
        String instructorEmailStr = "";

        for (Instructor instructor : allInstructors) {
            if(instructor.getId() == instructorID) {
                instructorNameStr = instructor.getName();
                instructorPhoneStr = instructor.getPhone();
                instructorEmailStr = instructor.getEmail();
            }
        }

        EditText instructorName = findViewById(R.id.instructor_name);
        instructorName.setText(instructorNameStr);
        EditText instructorPhone = findViewById(R.id.instructor_phone);
        instructorPhone.setText(instructorPhoneStr);
        EditText instructorEmail = findViewById(R.id.instructor_email);
        instructorEmail.setText(instructorEmailStr);

        List<Assessment> assessmentsInCourse = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Assessment assessment : allAssessments) {
            if(assessment.getCourseID() == courseCalled) {
                assessmentsInCourse.add(assessment);
            }
        }

        String[] titles = new String[assessmentsInCourse.size()];
        final int[] assessmentIDs = new int[assessmentsInCourse.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for(Assessment assessment : assessmentsInCourse) {
            titles[i] = assessment.getTitle();
            assessmentIDs[i] = assessment.getId();
            i++;
        }

        final android.widget.ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, titles);
        final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.assessment_list_view);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                int currentAssessment = assessmentIDs[(int)id];
                System.out.println("set to clicked id, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);

                Assessment assessment = getAssessment(currentAssessment);

                String assessmentNameStr = assessment.getTitle();
                String assessmentTypeStr = assessment.getType();
                String assessmentDueStr = assessment.getDueDate();

                EditText assessmentName = findViewById(R.id.assessment_title);
                assessmentName.setText(assessmentNameStr);
                EditText assessmentType = findViewById(R.id.assessment_type);
                assessmentType.setText(assessmentTypeStr);
                EditText assessmentDue = findViewById(R.id.assessment_due);
                assessmentDue.setText(assessmentDueStr);

                System.out.println("end of onclickListener, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("After listener, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);
    }

    public void deleteCourseButton(View v) {

        if(courseCalled == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this,
                    "No saved term to delete,\nplease use back button.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            for(Course course : allCourses) {
                if(course.getId() == courseCalled) {
                    db.deleteCourse(courseCalled);
                    TermActivity.numberOfCourses--;
                }
            }
            this.recreate();
        }
    }

    public void saveCourseButton(View v) {

        Course saveCourse = new Course();

        for(Course course : allCourses) {
            if(courseCalled == course.getId()) {
                saveCourse = course;
            }
        }

        String courseTitle;
        int courseTermID = saveCourse.getTermID();
        int courseInstructorID = saveCourse.getInstructorID();
        String courseStartDateStr;
        String courseEndDateStr;
        String courseStatusStr;
        String courseNoteStr;

        EditText courseName = findViewById(R.id.course_title);
        courseTitle = courseName.getText().toString();
        EditText courseStartDate = findViewById(R.id.course_start_date);
        courseStartDateStr = courseStartDate.getText().toString();
        EditText courseEndDate = findViewById(R.id.course_end_date);
        courseEndDateStr = courseEndDate.getText().toString();
        EditText courseStatus = findViewById(R.id.course_status);
        courseStatusStr = courseStatus.getText().toString();
        EditText courseNote = findViewById(R.id.course_note);
        courseNoteStr = courseNote.getText().toString();

        String instructorNameStr;
        String instructorPhoneStr;
        String instructorEmailStr;

        EditText instructorName = findViewById(R.id.instructor_name);
        instructorNameStr = instructorName.getText().toString();
        EditText instructorPhone = findViewById(R.id.instructor_phone);
        instructorPhoneStr = instructorPhone.getText().toString();
        EditText instructorEmail = findViewById(R.id.instructor_email);
        instructorEmailStr = instructorEmail.getText().toString();

        if(courseTitle.isEmpty()
                || courseStartDateStr.isEmpty()
                || courseEndDateStr.isEmpty()
                || courseStatusStr.isEmpty()
                || courseNoteStr.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Please fill course fields.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if(instructorNameStr.isEmpty()
                || instructorPhoneStr.isEmpty()
                || instructorEmailStr.isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Please fill instructor fields.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Check if new course courseCalled is -1 or if not update with id in courseCalled
            if(courseCalled == -1) {
                courseTermID = TermActivity.activeTerm.getId();

                // Insert new instructor and get their ID back
                courseInstructorID = (int) db.insertInstructor(instructorNameStr,
                        instructorPhoneStr, instructorEmailStr);

                courseCalled = (int) db.insertCourse(courseTermID,
                        courseInstructorID, courseTitle, courseStartDateStr,
                        courseEndDateStr, courseStatusStr, courseNoteStr);

                allCourses = db.getCourses();

                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "New course saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                this.recreate();
            } else {
                // Insert new instructor and get their ID back
                courseInstructorID = (int) db.insertInstructor(instructorNameStr,
                        instructorPhoneStr, instructorEmailStr);

                db.updateCourse(courseCalled, courseTermID, courseInstructorID, courseTitle,
                        courseStartDateStr, courseEndDateStr, courseStatusStr, courseNoteStr);

                allCourses = db.getCourses();

                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Course updated.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                this.recreate();
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveAssessmentButton(View v) {

        String assessmentNameStr;
        String assessmentTypeStr;
        String assessmentDueStr;

        EditText assessmentName = findViewById(R.id.assessment_title);
        assessmentNameStr = assessmentName.getText().toString();
        EditText assessmentType = findViewById(R.id.assessment_type);
        assessmentTypeStr = assessmentType.getText().toString();
        EditText assessmentDue = findViewById(R.id.assessment_due);
        assessmentDueStr = assessmentDue.getText().toString();

        if(assessmentDueStr.isEmpty() || assessmentNameStr.isEmpty() || assessmentTypeStr.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Please fill all fields.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (currentAssessment == -1) {

                currentAssessment = (int) db.insertAssessment(courseCalled, assessmentNameStr,
                        assessmentTypeStr, assessmentDueStr);

                allAssessments = db.getAssessments();

                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Assessment added.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.recreate();
            } else {

                db.updateAssessment(currentAssessment, courseCalled, assessmentNameStr,
                        assessmentTypeStr, assessmentDueStr);

                allAssessments = db.getAssessments();

                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Assessment updated.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.recreate();
            }
        }
    }

    public void newAssessmentButton(View v) {

        EditText assessmentName = findViewById(R.id.assessment_title);
        assessmentName.setText("");
        EditText assessmentType = findViewById(R.id.assessment_type);
        assessmentType.setText("");
        EditText assessmentDue = findViewById(R.id.assessment_due);
        assessmentDue.setText("");

        currentAssessment = -1;
    }

    public void deleteAssessmentButton(View v) {
        System.out.println("start of deleteAssessmentButton, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);
        if(currentAssessment == -1) {
            System.out.println("currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);

            EditText assessmentName = findViewById(R.id.assessment_title);
            assessmentName.setText("");
            EditText assessmentType = findViewById(R.id.assessment_type);
            assessmentType.setText("");
            EditText assessmentDue = findViewById(R.id.assessment_due);
            assessmentDue.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "No assessment chosen.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("sending to delete assessment id: " + currentAssessment);
            long result = db.deleteAssessment(currentAssessment);

            if(result == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Assessment NOT deleted.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(CourseActivity.this, "Assessment deleted.  result = " + result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                allAssessments = db.getAssessments();

                this.recreate();
            }
        }
    }

    public Assessment getAssessment(int id) {
        Assessment assessment = new Assessment();

        for(Assessment asmt : allAssessments) {
            if(asmt.getId() == id) {
                assessment = asmt;
            }
        }
        return assessment;
    }
}
```

I've checked and rechecked the code, and can find no place between clicking the listView and clicking the delete button where it should reset the activity.  Is this automatically happening after my listView onClick?  Is there another way to keep track of an ID?

Comment: Like DigitalNinja said: lower-scoped variables override ones in higher-level scopes with the same name.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot!  I'd up vote the great answers if people didn't down vote me so I don't have enough rep to do so..  My third question, people just don't give a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have two `currentAssessment` variables. One that is private to the class and another that is confined to the scope of `onItemClick`. Once `onItemClick` exits you've lost that assignment, and anywhere else where you're referencing `currentAssessment` is the one that belongs to the class, which would still be -1.

The fix would be to use the class `currentAssessment` for your `onItemClick`.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            currentAssessment = assessmentIDs[(int)id];
            System.out.println("set to clicked id, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);

            Assessment assessment = getAssessment(currentAssessment);

            String assessmentNameStr = assessment.getTitle();
            String assessmentTypeStr = assessment.getType();
            String assessmentDueStr = assessment.getDueDate();

            EditText assessmentName = findViewById(R.id.assessment_title);
            assessmentName.setText(assessmentNameStr);
            EditText assessmentType = findViewById(R.id.assessment_type);
            assessmentType.setText(assessmentTypeStr);
            EditText assessmentDue = findViewById(R.id.assessment_due);
            assessmentDue.setText(assessmentDueStr);

            System.out.println("end of onclickListener, currentAssessment = " + currentAssessment);
        }
    });
```